# Filling Tear Drop Css3

Tags: html, css, animation

i Tried To Fill The Tear Drop In Order To Use It As A Preloader

Here Is The Code

```css
#drop {
  margin: 100px auto; 
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e74c3c;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#drop::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #e74c3c;
  width: 100%; 
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wipe 5s cubic-bezier(.2,.6,.8,.4) forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes wipe {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="drop"></div>
```

I Tried To Use Transform And Margin But It Failed

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used shorthand for `border-radius` and the other changes which i have made is for `pseudo` element

- doubled the size of the `pseudo` element.
- position the `pseudo` element at the center
- positioned it at the bottom of the element with `transform: translate(-100%, 10%) rotate(45deg);`
- In keyframes i am moving the `pseudo` element to the top

```css
  #drop {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50% 0 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e74c3c;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#drop::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #e74c3c;
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 10%) rotate(45deg);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: wipe 5s cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4) forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes wipe {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 10%) rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  }
```

```html
<div id="drop"></div>
```

Comment: An explanation, instead of just a code dump, is usually very helpful.

Comment: @Vitorino fernandes wowww it's awesome , Thanks So Much For This , God Bless You :) <3